# Redirecting depending on directory

Tags: server, nginx

On my current load balancer I have set it up to redirect to my cluster like this:

```
upstream myapp1 {
    server 192.168.0.20; #RP1
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myapp1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Which works fine.

But I have a directory within my web server which has a lot of 'stress' behind it `www.example.com/local/`

I was wondering if there was a method to redirect to the load balancer (the most powerful and the current server) `192.168.1.10` so that it will take all the traffic to the local directory `/var/www/local/`. While the `upstream myapp1` will redirect all the other directories.

---

### I have tried this:

Okay so the directory in which I want to be used on `192.168.1.10` is `wwww.example.com/local` and on the server (`192.168.1.10`) it is at `/local` I have given this directory permissions like this:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /local
```

I have then put this in the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` on `192.168.1.10`:

```
upstream myapp1 {
    server 192.168.0.20; #RP1
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myapp1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location /local/ {
        root /local;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    server_name 192.168.1.10;

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }
}
```

But it is not working, I get the error log

> *1 "/local/local/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory)`

Why is it looking at the directory `/local/local/`... Also I have now added that file and directory for testing purposes and I get the error log

> conflicting server name "192.168.1.10" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

Okay now I have sorted that by removing other files in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`.

Now I am just getting a 404 page when I access `www.example.com/local/` and no error logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify multiple [`location`](http://nginx.org/r/location) directives that handle the requests differently:

```
upstream myapp1 {
    server 192.168.0.20; #RP1
}
upstream myapp2 {
    server 192.168.0.10; # some other machine?
}

server {
    listen 80;

    # server requests to myapp1 if there is no more specific match
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myapp1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    # serve requests to this path from a different host    
    location /foo/ {
        proxy_pass http://myapp2;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    # serve requests to this path from the local disk
    location /this-server/ {
        root /var/www;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so if `myapp1` has multiple 'servers' it will act as a load balancer still?

Comment: can you see the edit?

Comment: @Maximilian What "does not work"? Have you checked your error and access logs? Have you read the documentation?

Comment: Sorry where are they? I am now trying to redirect to a virtual host on the local machine if the url is `example.com/foo` but getting a 400 bad request

Comment: @Maximilian The error log is at /var/log/nginx/error.log. Please edit your question with a configuration which already works and describe what extensions you are trying to make. Your question is too vague to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: I have edited the question again! Do you understand it more?

Comment: @Maximilian Ok it is a bit clearer now. You want to make this nginx server handle all requests to `/foo/` while passing all other requests to 192.168.0.20. Then the configuration as provided should work. Are you sure that the posted configuration is complete? Please check the error logs before posting again.

Comment: any ideas Lekensteyn?

Comment: @Maximilian Please look up the documentation for the [root directive](http://nginx.org/r/root) and the [alias directive](http://nginx.org/r/alias) of nginx.